# Changing which graphics card drives the laptop display

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display

Wanted to know if it was possible to change the laptop display to run using the dedicated graphics card instead of the on-board one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That display is not representative of your actual hardware and is for indication only.

The actual underlying hardware is quite complicated and while the device that actually pushes data to your display is the Intel graphics device where the image data is constructed and rendered can change per application as configured elsewhere in that tool.

Graphics is rendered by whichever device is appropriate (and configured) and are composited together by the built in graphics hardware.

From the [Nvidia Whitepaper](https://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/optimus_technology_uk.html) that describes how it works your display hardware pipeline looks something like this:

[image]

Unless you are having problems then there is little point in having the dedicated graphics permanently on, it will just cause your laptop to consume more power when not doing demanding tasks.

Comment: Interesting. In that case, I have another question (which is why I posted this in the first place). I have a laptop screen that is rated to support 130% of the sRGB color gamut and I am seeing over-saturated reds/yellows. One post on the LTT forum mentioned that the problem was with Windows not being a color managed OS. What can I do to resolve the issue? I have tried many ICC profiles but that doesn't fix the issue

Comment: I'm afraid that is something I've never had experience of. Properly setting up colour profiles is not something I've ever needed to do... It would be worth asking a new question detailing your setup, what problems you are having with the display and what you have tried.